# Opencart 2 caching

Tags: caching, opencart

Has opencart 2.1 a cache system apart from modification?

I'm trying to restyle an opencart 2.1 site.

I've modified `catalog/view/theme/my-theme/template/product/product.tpl`
but I'm not able to see my updates.

The site has only 1 modification that affects Admin area...I've also tried to disable it and update cache, but without success.

I've tried to open site in another browser, but nothing.

Finally I've tried to rename `product.tpl` to `product111.tpl` (also in `view/theme/default/product`)... but the original product page is still loaded.

Does someone know why this happens?

UPDATE : I haven't found a solution, so I made a fresh installation, applied custom theme and then copied modified files... everything is Ok now. If I modify product.tpl, all changes are visible in product page.

Comment: go to admin and refresh modifications

Comment: already done, as I said ;)

Comment: What is your theme? Maybe your theme has its own cache system?

Comment: I haven't checked if theme has its own cache...I'll check. Thanks

Comment: Go to admin panel => design > `Theme Editor > product > product.tpl` edit file and save it

Comment: @JagrutiMetaliya, OpenCart 2.x hasn't a them editor by default.

Comment: then try to clear cach with the putty

Comment: theme is fastor and has not a cache system, only css and js compression (it's disabled by the way). I've cleared system/storage/cache, but there were no files related to product. I'm stuck... product page is still loading even if there is no product.tpl in all theme directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you have vQmod installed there is a vqcache also.

You can check to see if you have vQmod installed like this:
yoursite.com/vqmod/install

It should usually clear itself, but if it doesn't then you can safely rename the vqcache folder to clear it.

The reason I say rename rather than delete is that sometimes a change to the cache will show an error which wasn't spotted when the original change was made and might prevent orders until it's fixed. If you rename then you can place the folder back and it will work again but of course you should fix the error when you can.

Comment: No vQmod installed :(